# Best LaTeX Editor

Tags: latex, text-editing

What's the best LaTeX editor you've used, and what would you recommend someone read to understand and become proficient with authoring papers/books in LaTeX?

Comment: Try flagging the mods; nobody else has that much rep either :)

Comment: Tagged it, but can't edit out your tagging request.

Comment: I edited out your paragraph, but I had to change the title because the length requirement was increased since then. :)

Comment: Both the questions of [editors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/1402) and [guides](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/1402) have been covered extensively on the TeX Stackexchange.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Emacs has excellent support for LaTeX.
Look for the [AUCTeX package](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/).
I never got the hang of LyX admittedly, but maybe it has improved since I last tried it.

And just to brag a little I have seen **Donald Knuth** using Emacs with my very own eyes:-)

Comment: Post flagged for bragging ;)

Comment: +1 for name-dropping.  I'm a proficient vi user myself, maybe I'll delve into emacs a little.

Comment: And I can use VIPER for Vi bindings in Emacs.  Sold.

Comment: You should also mention that RefTeX is the best thing ever

Comment: Also Leslie Lamport, author of LaTeX, uses Emacs and [supplied](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=auctex.git;a=blob;f=doc/history.texi;hb=HEAD) to AUCTeX the descriptions of error messages.

Answer (score 15):

I recommend beginner to start with [LyX](http://www.lyx.org/) as it is close to being a [WYSIWYG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editor for LaTeX (it's actually [WYSIWYM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYM)). It's quite friendly runs on Linux/Unix, Windows, and Mac OS X so it can serve pretty much anybody.

A more advance version is [LEd (LaTeX Editor)](http://www.latexeditor.org) but this one is Windows Only.

Comment: LyX is NOT a WYSIWYG editor, it is a WYSIWYM editor.

Comment: Thank you Stefan for the comment on WYSIWYM. I've corrected the post to reflect what I meant and included reference to it.

Answer (score 15):

For my latest work I used [TeXnicCenter](http://www.texniccenter.org/). It is pretty powerful, but also a bit complex to understand in the beginning ...

Answer (score 7):

If you are a programmer and use Eclipse, there is [an Eclipse plugin](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/) that you can use to edit files. However, you need something like mikTeX to produce a PDF or PS file.

Answer (score 7):

On Mac OS X, I use [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) with its LaTex Bundle, and [Skim](http://skim-app.sourceforge.net/) as a PDF reader. On Windows, [WinShell](http://www.winshell.de/) is a pretty good editor.

Answer (score 6):

I use MacVim on Mac OS X and a makefile to create the pdf.

Answer (score 5):

To make a start: you can use the  [Lyx](http://www.lyx.org/) editor and look at some online guides such as [Tobi Oetiker's *The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX2e*](http://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf) followed later by books that address specific requirements (Maths, science, graphics).

As confidence increases:
Move to either an editor you already use and are comfortable with (e.g. emacs with the auctex extensions or vim/gvim with the latexsuite extensions) or a cross-platform editor such as TeXworks.

Useful texts at that stage can include:
[Kopka & Daly (2003), *Guide to LaTeX* (4th edn)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Guide-LATEX-Helmut-Kopka/dp/0321173856)

[Mittelbach & Goosens (2004), *The LaTeX Companion* (2nd edn)](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Latex-Companion-Frank-Mittelbach/dp/0201362996)

but you may also want something more 'practical' such as [Kottwitz's *LaTeX Beginner's Guide*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/LaTeX-Beginner%2527s-Guide-Stefan-Kottwitz/dp/1847199860/).

Samples from users in the same field or producing similar documents are also very helpful, as are their recommendations for books and on-line tutorials.

Before much longer you'll want to have a look at the original and classic book by [Knuth: *The TeXbook*](https://www.amazon.co.uk/TeXbook-Donald-Knuth/dp/0201134489/)

Answer (score 5):

While Lyx is a nice WYSIWYG editor, if you want to learn latex I would say use a text editor with syntax highlighting or something like [TexShop](http://www.uoregon.edu/~koch/texshop/), which is made for tex editing.

Comment: worth mentioning - OSX only

Answer (score 4):

I really like [Kile](http://kile.sf.net).

The newest version (2.1) written for KDE4 has some issues at the moment but the KDE3.5 version (2.0) is rock solid. The integration with KDE is very good, the main editing environment being katepart.

The most impressive feature for me is the ability to preview selected text or the current environment in a tab in the editor window. There is also good auto-complete support and easy to use symbol lists.

Comment: Love kile too, with all the automagic functionality.

Answer (score 3):

I feel like I should give [WinEdt](http://www.winedt.com/) a mention; I used it to write up my master's dissertation. It's Windows only, and it's not WYSIWY{G,M}, but it's got lots and lots of features specifically for working with LaTeX.

It's shareware, and I've managed to lose my licence, but if I had to do any LaTeX work on Windows again, I would buy another copy in an instant.

Answer (score 1):

I second all the plugs for [LyX](http://www.lyx.org).  For ease and simplicity, it's great.  But I had trouble configuring it to do some things: adjusting spacing between `itemize` items, etc.  I always ended up tinkering with the TeX source in a separate editor.

For editing TeX directly, I use [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/), which is basic but has a lot of nice features, such as one-click rendering.

Answer (score 1):

I use Vim and it works.

Answer (score 1):

[Inlage](http://www.inlage.com) is a very modern LaTeX software with Windows7 tablet pc support. It has an intelligent autocompletion for many commands and symbols with descriptions, spellchecker, office table import, docking system, report window...

It's very easy to handle, e.g. setting up SumatraPDF with inverse/forwards should be not a problem for LaTeX beginners and takes not much time.