# Using LaTeX to create professional PDF documents

Tags: windows, pdf, latex

During our MS thesis studies, I remember that some of my friends were using LaTeX to write their theses. All I can remember is that it was like an old MS-DOS screen, and the program was linked to some files to arrange page margins, paper size, headers, footers, etc. Friends were saying it is hard to learn LaTeX but once you learn, it is easier than MS Word to finish writing your thesis.

Now, I just don't know where to start. I am willing to learn LaTeX but I really don't know much about it. Is it a programming language or a software? Where should I start with? What software do I need? When I type LaTeX in Google, it fetches too many pages which is confusing for me. Any recommendations for online documents, and good web sites covering everything about it? TIA.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

LaTeX is a markup language, meaning that everything in a document is about *what* it is rather than how it looks like. The final formatting is done by a program (e.g. pdflatex) that translates your input source files to an output file (e.g. a PDF file).

This relieves you from having to worry about the *looks* of your document before you even have the content done. A similar workflow is possible in programs like Microsoft Word, when you define a style sheet and e.g. format headings as `h1` rather as "bold, 15pt, sans-serif", but to me this happens much more natural in markup languages like LaTeX.

When I started to learn LaTeX I learned pretty much everything to get me started from [this guide](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/english/lshort.pdf).

One can do actual programming in the TeX (the underlying language in LaTeX) and there are other possibilities like Lua, but you do not need this to write documents.

LaTeX can be written in any text editor (probably what you saw before), but there are also specialized editors (environments) available that make this very easy for new users:

- [Lyx](http://www.lyx.org), [TeXnicCenter](http://www.texniccenter.org/): show you immediately how your document will look
- [AUCTeX](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/): extremely productive (La)TeX plugin for `emacs` (in fact the only reason for me to use emacs these days), with [`preview`](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/preview-latex.html) you even get a look at how your figures and equations will look like inside `emacs`
- [VIM-LaTeX](http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/): LaTeX-plugin for `vim`, good for quick stuff

The plus points of LaTeX in comparison to using e.g. Microsoft Word for me are:

- you stay focused on your content
- making professional looking documents extremely easy, e.g. numbering of figures, references, extremely good support for math markup
- your university might already provide a LaTeX class/style that makes everything look like required
- LaTeX has very loose limits on how big your document can be, and it doesn't crash like Word seems to when your document gets very big

Comment: Note though, that in practially every at least medium-sized real-world document there are those weird corner cases where LaTeX's automagic handling doesn't quite do what you want and you have to jump through a few hoops to achieve the desired result. This has happened to me nearly every time I used LaTeX to write a document longer than 5 pages. The built-in algorithms perform quite well but still often require some manual intervention to get a good result (yes, figures may also disappear from the document entirely, just like in Word).

Comment: Also don't believe the myth that you don't have to know anything about typesetting and LaTeX will magically create beautiful documents for you. When used without knowledge the results are equally awful as Word's, just maybe with a silk robe draped over them—which doesn't change that much, it makes the result just look better in its ugliness. For example: While you won't get unusually long spaces you'll get lines that overflow the right border. Figures or tables might go beyond page boundaries when layout fails. You can easily get ”right quotation marks” on both sides if not paying attention.

Comment: @Johannes Rössel: Thanks for sharing the dark corners of LaTeX.

Comment: @Johannes I never had any of the problems you mentioned in years. And as for the "beautiful myth", if you stick to using LaTeX markup and stay away from formatting stuff yourself, the result should be consitent and yes, beautiful.

Comment: @honk: You still need to know about several things you have to do manually, such as writing quotes as `\`\``/`"` or using `\left` and `\right` in math for matching parentheses/bracket pairs. And those are among the more easy ones to remember. Heck, I've even seen many of those mistakes done by people using LaTeX for years and imho it's as ugly a sight as a badly formatted Word document. That's no to say you can't make good-looking documents but knowledge of typography is needed in any case; that's nothing a computer program will handle fully automatic for you—not even LaTeX.

Comment: @Jo what you consider ugly stuff is what I call proper markup. And it has nothing to do with typography.

Comment: Chiming in with a TeXworks[1] mention. I use vim with latex-suite for myself, but I have friends doing large projects in TeXworks, and they say it does the job well.

[1]: http://www.tug.org/texworks/

Comment: I agree with Rössel. For example I frequently find spacing in math formulas too small and tables using <tabular> look supremely awful without some extra work.  But for professional-looking math, I can't think of anything better (in the sense of beauty and ease) than LaTeX.  But if you need your document to look unique, I think it would be easier to use something WYSIWYG like Framemaker or even MS Word.

Answer (score 3):

I found this to be a good point to start with LaTeX
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Absolute_Beginners

LaTeX is not a programming language it's a "Document Markup Language" and does not refer to a specific software.

Written LaTeX looks like:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\title{\LaTeX}
\date{}
\begin{document}
  \maketitle 
  \LaTeX example...
```

A LaTeX compiler (if you use windows you could use http://miktex.org) will make sense of this and write a proper document (PDF usually)

Answer (score 2):

The other answers cover the basics of LaTeX quite well. To get you started, here are some SW recommendations:

- If you're on Linux, almost all distributions include TeX and LaTeX. Just install the relevant packages, usually they are named something like "tex" or "texlive".
- For Windows, get TeXLive from their site: http://www.tug.org/texlive/
- On MacOS X, get [MacTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacTeX)

After installing it, you can use one of the tutorials above to get started.

The files that you write LaTeX in are just text files, so you could use Notepad to write LaTeX. However, it's helpful to have an editor that helps you a bit.

For starters, you could use something like Notepad++ or vim . You can also use a more full-featured environment like TeXnic Center, that's a matter of personal preference. The result will always be the same, as they all just invoke LaTeX in the end.

Additional info:

Also see here: [Best LaTeX Editor](https://superuser.com/questions/3425/latex-editors)

You might also want to try LyX. It is not LaTeX (but based on LaTeX), but a bit more userfriendly. If you later want to use LaTeX directly, it's not difficult to migrate.